# Error when building frama-clang: Unbound module Parameter_sig

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I downloaded `frama-clang` from [here](http://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html), installed `opam` and used it to install Ocaml 2.02.3. Then I built frama-c Aluminium (which went fine) and following that I ran `./configure` and then `make`.

In the latter step, I get an error saying:

> File "frama_Clang_option.mli", line 26, characters 22-42:
>
> Error: Unbound module Parameter_sig
>
> make: *** [frama_Clang_option.cmi] Error 2

I've been googling for hours now but I didn't find out how to install that (seemingly) missing module `Parameter_sig`. I am sure I have installed every required software (llvm, ocaml etc.) so what is missing and how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Do you have `frama-c` in your path? `Parameter_sig` should come from in `$(frama-c -print-lib-path)/parameter_sig.cmi` .

Comment: A possible explanation is the presence of two frama-c installations, one within a package and one in opam. Have you checked if `frama-c --version` is Aluminium and if `frama-c -print-lib-path` points to the opam directory?

Comment: @Anne if this were the case, this should have been detected at `./configure` time. @Franck's explanation is more likely given the information available.